# Diophantine equation in $\mathbb{Z_+}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

> Solve over positive integers:
>   $$\left (1+\frac{1}{a} \right ) \left (1+\frac{1}{b} \right ) \left (1+\frac{1}{c} \right )=2$$

My claim is there aren't solutions, but I can't find a complete proof.

Comment: Maybe rewrite $\frac{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)}{abc}=2$

Comment: $(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})(1+\frac{1}{15}) =2$.

Comment: Somehow an extra prime factor 2 must be squeezed into either a+1 or b+1 or c+1

Comment: @Ahmad: i didn't find that solution... now i understand why i didn't conclude anything from my attempts to prove that there wasn't solution.

Comment: $(2,4,15),(2,5,9),(2,6,7),(3,4,5),(3,3,8)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following idea works.

Let $a=1+x$, $b=1+y$ and $c=1+z$.

Hence, we need to solve
$$6+2(x+y+z)=xyz,$$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negative integer numbers.

Thus,
$$6+2(x+y)=z(xy-2)\geq xy-2,$$
which gives $$(x-2)(y-2)\leq12.$$

It's not so many cases.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment :

We can assume $1\le a\le b\le c$. For $c\le 1000$, there are the following solutions :

```
? for(a=1,1000,for(b=a,1000,for(c=b,1000,if((1+1/a)*(1+1/b)*(1+1/c)==2,print([a,
b,c])))))
[2, 4, 15]
[2, 5, 9]
[2, 6, 7]
[3, 3, 8]
[3, 4, 5]
```

No idea, whether further solutions exist. But it is clear that we cannot have $a\ge 4$ because then, we would have $$(1+\frac{1}{a})(1+\frac{1}{b})(1+\frac{1}{c})\le 1.25^3<2$$

Comment: Well, using what you said: $a \in \{2,3 \}$. Now we have two simpler equations, easy solvable we a similar idea.

Comment: extending the argument as L.A. mentions, for a=2, b can't be larger than 7, For a=3, b cant be larger than 4.

Comment: In fact, fixing $a$ leads to an equation with only $2$ unknwons. The solutions can easily be calculated and it turns out that there are only the $5$ mentioned solutions.